# Javascript programming, function not defined error

Tags: javascript, html, function

Here is my code. Sorry for improper indentation.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
   pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>게시판</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/addScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.popupWindow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/infobee.common.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 var html = '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
    html += '<tr height="5"><td width="5"></td></tr>';
    html += '<tr style="background:url('+'img/table_mid.gif'+') repeat-x; text-align:center;">';
    html += '<td width="5"><img src="img/table_left.gif" width="5" height="30" /></td>';
    html += '<td width="73">번호</td>';
    html += '<td width="379">제목</td>';
    html += '<td width="73">작성자</td>';
    html += '<td width="164">작성일</td>';
    html += '<td width="58">조회수</td>';
    html += '<td width="7"><img src="img/table_right.gif" width="5" height="30" /></td>';
    html += '</tr>';


 var domainText = getDomain();

 function getDomain() {
 return "localhost:8080";
 }

 function getForumRow() {

     var userId = "neogeoss";
     var passwd = "1311";

    //Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

   // var row = document.getElementById("1stRow");

     var params = "userId="+userId+"&userPassword="+passwd;

   $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
     url: "http://"+domainText+"/secure_server/test/test.do",
     callback: "callback",
     dataType: "jsonp",
     data:params,
     success: function(data) {
         var htmlInner = html;
         $.each(data, function(k, v){
             htmlInner += "<tr height='25' align='center'>"
                htmlInner += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                    htmlInner += "<td>"+v["num"]+"</td>";
                    htmlInner +=    "<td align='left'>"+v["title"]+"</td>";
                    htmlInner += "<td align='center'>"+v["writer"]+"cccc</td>";
                    htmlInner += "<td align='center'>"+v["date"]+"</td>";
                    htmlInner += "<td align='center'>"+v["like"]+"</td>";
                    htmlInner += "<td align='center'>"+v["open"]+"</td>";
                    htmlInner += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                    htmlInner += "</tr>";
                    htmlInner += "<tr height="1" bgcolor="#D2D2D2"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>";
                    htmlInner += "<tr height="1" bgcolor="#82B5DF"><td colspan="6" width="752"></td></tr>";




             });
                htmlInner += '</table>'

                $("#list").html(htmlInner);

                $("#test").attr("disabled", true);



            /* if(myMap.get("번호")){
                row.insertCell(myMap.get("번호")).style.width = "73";
             } else if (myMap.get("글쓴이")) {
                row.insertCell(myMap.get("글쓴이")).style.width = "73"; 
             } else if (myMap.get("제목")) {
                row.insertCell(myMap.get("제목")).style.width = "379";
             } else if (myMap.get("등록일")) {
                row.insertCell(myMap.get("등록일")).style.width = "164";  
             } else if (myMap.get("추천")) {
                 row.insertCell(myMap.get("추천")).style.width = "58";  
             } else if (myMap.get("조회")) {
                 row.insertCell(myMap.get("조회")).style.width = "58";
             }*/

         }
     });
}
 function init(){
        var htmlInner = html;

    htmlInner += '<tr align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30">'
    htmlInner += '<td colspan="6">등록된 글이 없습니다.</td>'
    htmlInner += '</tr>'
    htmlInner += '<tr height="1" bgcolor="#D2D2D2"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>'
    htmlInner += '<tr height="1" bgcolor="#82B5DF"><td colspan="6" width="752"></td></tr>'
    htmlInner += '</table>'

    $("#list").html(htmlInner);
    $("#test").attr("disabled", false);

}



    </script>
  </head>
<body onload="javascript:getForumRow()">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
     <tr height="5"><td width="5"></td></tr>
    <tr style="background:url('img/table_mid.gif') repeat-x; text-align:center;">
  <td width="5"><img src="img/table_left.gif" width="5" height="30" /></td>
   <td width="73">번호</td>
   <td width="73">글쓴이</td>
   <td width="379">제목</td>
   <td width="164">등록일</td>
   <td width="58">추천</td>
   <td width="58">조회</td>
   <td width="7"><img src="img/table_right.gif" width="5" height="30" /></td>
  </tr>
<tr height="25" align="center">
</tr>
  <tr height="1" bgcolor="#D2D2D2"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>

  <tr id="1stRow">

  </tr>


 <tr height="1" bgcolor="#82B5DF"><td colspan="8" width="752"></td></tr>
 </table>

<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tr><td colspan="4" height="5"></td></tr>
 <tr align="center">
 <td><input type=button value="글쓰기"    OnClick="window.location='boardWrite.jsp'"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

I am trying to show a forum with a list of Q&As. 
When I run it, i get errors.

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement BulletinBoardColumns.jsp:63:32
ReferenceError: getForumRow is not defined BulletinBoardColumns.jsp:1:12

I cannot find any mistakes.. So ask you guys for help..

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();` is Java, not Javascript.

Comment: Check your Javascript console, you should be getting a syntax error because of that line. That prevents the rest of the script from being loaded, so the function doesn't get defined.

Comment: I commented it out so that it won't prevent loading the page. But i still get some errors.

Comment: Please provide the shortest code necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: I do not know whether it is possible. If i knew the shortest necessary code, i would not post this question. HTML problem occurs at every possible location so I had to upload the entire page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Following code is not javascript code. Javascript has [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object, [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap).
`HashMap` is for java.

Replace aboce code with

```
var myMap = new Map();
```

All other code looks fine for working.

Comment: Thank you.. It was  a problem to be solved. However, I got another error after debugging it.